# Redefine ToC entry style without packages

Tags: table-of-contents, packages

I've redefined the section, subsection and subsubsection styles in my preamble as

```
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}%
}

\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
}
```

And I want it to appear the same way in the ToC. I've tried using tocloft but it messes around with other stuff. How could I do it without the use of any package?

Comment: so you want to change the body but not the TOC?  Or do you want it to change both the body as well as the TOC entries?

Comment: @MaxGraves: It is clear through the OP: "And I want it to appear the same way in the ToC." He established a style in the body and wants to apply this to the TOC.

Comment: @Ruben I would disagree, this seems to be a bit of an ambiguous statement...does 'the same way in the ToC' mean the same as his definition or the same as the default?  I wanted clarification before attempting to provide a solution.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. But Ruben got what I mean: I established a style for the body and want that same style applied to the TOC :)

Comment: Most of this is related to extra vertical glue; does it make sense in a TOC?

Comment: @jfbu yes, because I have a set of rules to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Well, found a solution :)

Placing in this piece of code at my preamble

```
\let\stdl@section\l@section
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \stdl@section{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase{#1}}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase{#2}}}
```

Did the deal. The same could be done to subsection and subsubsecion ;)
There is only a small detail left: special characters don't get uppercase, such as:

> á é í ó ú à õ ô

And I have no idea why placing an `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\uppercase` gets random errors when generating the PDF. Will dig in a little bit more and see what happens.

@Update
Guess there is a problem with `\MakeUppercase` and hyperref package. I removed the hyperref package and changed all the `\uppercase` for `\MakeUppercase` and it works as charm. The codes I actually used to modify the ToC appearance is:

```
\let\stdl@section\l@section
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \stdl@section{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#2}}

\let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
  \stdl@subsection{\normalfont\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#2}}

\let\stdl@subsubsection\l@subsubsection
\renewcommand*{\l@subsubsection}[2]{%
  \stdl@subsubsection{\bfseries{#1}}{#2}}
```